debug proxy mitm (RustMatrixClientFactory)
I'm trying to follow the steps in https://github.com/element-hq/element-x-android/blob/develop/docs/debug_proxying.md but i can't seem to find RustMatrixClientFactory.create() method, I only find this io.element.android.libraries.matrix.impl.RustMatrixClientFactory$create$2
I'm not sure if they are the same thing, if so how to proceed the next step?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a project specific issue and has already been answered in a cross post of the same user in the project's issue tracker https://github.com/element-hq/element-x-android/issues/2812
